# Database - Pivot based on RowType within single table (without self join)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pivot

I have the below table in Oracle, and I need to convert this into multiple columns based on RecType.

I wrote a self join on the table but RecType has 5 types and it's too big a query, is there any easier way I can do this?

Table I am selecting from:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add more recTypes as you need.. this is not dynamic and you would need to hardcode recTypes etc.. but works

```
SELECT  recNo, value1, value2, value3
  FROM  (
             SELECT t.recNo, t.rectype, max(t.value) value
             FROM   mytable t
             GROUP BY t.recType, t.RECNO
        )
 PIVOT  (
            max(value) FOR recType IN (103 value1, 191 value2, 108 value3)
        )
```

Comment: Thank you Bala, I am getting error executing this query "ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values

Comment: If your RecType column is a char/varchar type, then you have to enclose those in single quotes

 recType IN ('103' value1, '191' value2, '108' value3) ) /

Comment: Hi Bala, Your qeury actaully worked, just that Oracle didn't like 'AS'. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pivot query:

```
SELECT RecNo, Value, RecType FROM tablename
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR RecType
    IN (103 AS Value1, 191 AS Value2, 108 AS Value3)
)
```

To add in your other two values, just tack them on in the same pattern as the Value1/2/3. This does assume that you always have only one unique `Value` for each RecType and RecNo, or else you will end up losing information.

Comment: @hsenpaws Great, I'm glad it worked! Please mark it as the accepted answer to let others know that this problem was solved :)